# 2 different types of user facebook access tokens?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token

I have set up a facebook app so people can post stuff from my site directly to facebook using the graph api.

I request offline access and manage_pages so that they don't have to be logged in to facebook, but just to my site.

I also have set up the ability to post to a fan page they are managing directly from the site.

both those things definitely work because i have a fan page and i authorized it on my site and am able to post stuff to it directly from my site.

the problem is that when i send the access token to facebook /accounts?access_token=XXX, nothing is being returned for some users even if they are definitely managing (they sent me a screenshot showing they were the manager of the page)

looking at the access tokens i noticed that mine looks like (this is fake):

200785063253279|561ec27497172e3ddvs32dsc.1-10002342352350235|kB2_OoBtsgscsVW2mKMijfNdvb0

while the users in question have an access token like (again - fake):

AAAC2nOrFTH0BAJjMgS3h22ADhirwsfweRT35235LGcZCGisrefwae5tSF535DGlLKJOIBMnrMnI324sfasdSFOIjo325sIigfWOE1aNbvd8wAZD

I can't help but notice the vast difference between the two. is there a reason? is that why i am not getting any page info when i send the request to facebook?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The first Access Token is the old access Token format and the second Access token is the new Access token format.

This new format was announced a year ago:
https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/497/
And rolled out last September:
https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2011/09/09/platform-updates--operation-developer-love/

Any new Access tokens you get from the system will be of the new format.

Comment: that makes sense i guess. but why wouldn't /accounts return anything? the user has sent me a screenshot which clearly shows that they are a manager of a fan page.

Comment: Have you tried the access token debugger to see if the access token is still valid? Perhaps they have expired? https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Comment: I didn't know that tool existed. The token is still valid. it doesn't have manage_pages as a scope though, I know they need to approve my app for that if i want to post to the fan page, but do i need to ask for that before I can see what pages they manage to begin with? I didn't think that was the case.

Comment: /accounts should not need special permissions. When happens when you go to https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token=<access_token_here>
Note the "/me" you need to specify the user whose accounts you wish to view.

Comment: when i go to /me/?access_token=XXX i get JSON for id,name,location,favorite_teams,gender,timezone &c. nothing about the pages the user is part of or anything - but i am not sure they should show up there anyways.

Comment: Sorry, that should be /me/accounts?access_token=XXXX , my comment link got messed up.

Comment: just {"data":[]}. but the user sent me a screenshot showing that they are an administrator for a page - hence the confusion.

Comment: Bizzare, does it work for your account and any pages you admin?

Comment: Yes. it works perfectly for my account - and since my account starts with the 200785063253279| and the user's did not i thought that was the problem.

Comment: This sounds like some other issue and is nothing to do with the access token format. Are you sure they are sending you a screenshot for the same user account as you have an access token for?